# Session attribute inside javascript function

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jsp, session

Is it possible to call a method on a session attribute in a jsp page, from a javascript function? This function should be called when a button from the user interface is clicked.

Comment: what you actually need?

Comment: I need to call a method on a Java object, for example a method like start(), in which some Java code will be executed. Is it possible?

Comment: @dorinmoldovan
Not possible see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript runs client side in the browser so will not normally interact with your Jsp code running server side

as @BackSlash said its true `The method will be called on page rendering, not on button click`

Comment: That won't work. The method will be called on page rendering, not on button click.

Comment: @BackSlash

Thanks for comment.Could you look at updated answer please?

Comment: Still wrong IMO. The OP wants to call a method on a session object, which is not what your code does.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it like ,

```
<input type="button" onclick="function(<%= sessObj %>)" />
```

and you can get it your function,

```
function myFunction( var sessObj ){
alert(var);
}
```